# What if a pool of computers are used to attack a blockchain and modify it in 51% of the network?

Tags: blockchain

I mean if a large computer pool is used to attack a blockchain and modify the copy of the blockchain in 51% of computers in the network.
Then due to consensus, the faulty blockchain will be replicated across the whole network. Thus changing the whole blockchain.

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=51%25+attack

Answer (score 2):

> I mean if a large computer pool is used to attack a blockchain and modify the copy of the blockchain in 51% of computers in the network. Then due to consensus, the faulty blockchain will be replicated across the whole network. Thus changing the whole blockchain.

It won't work. Large computers are *terrible* at mining. It's like trying to use a jet plane to get billions of watermelons across a street. Sure, jet planes are big and powerful, but they're completely the wrong tool for that particular job.